# Windows Server Containers mixing host/container OS

Tags: containers, windows-server-2016

Is is possible to have Windows Server (the big one with UI) as host OS and Windows Server Nano as container OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be yes, but I haven't tried it with Nano myself.

What I do have running, however, is Windows Server with GUI, which in turn runs  dozen Windows Server Core containers. Since you can select either Core or Nano as the container OS, I don't see why would you have any problem with Nano.

The reason I didn't try Nano is because it supports only 64-bit apps, which is, unfortunately, not something I have available right now.